# Eloquent doesn't recognize my alias

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've a query to search users with certain distance :

```php
$q->addSelect(DB::raw(
    '( acos(cos(radians(' . Auth::user()->latitude . '))' .
        '* cos( radians( users.latitude ) )' .
        '* cos( radians( users.longitude )' .
        '- radians(' . Auth::user()->longitude . ') )' .
        '+ sin( radians(' . Auth::user()->latitude . ') )' .
        '* sin( radians( users.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'
));
$q->having('distance', '<', $search->distance);
```

I get this error : *Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause'*.

When I run the query in PhpMyAdmin with the return of `$q->toSql();`, my query works?!

Comment: did you try ->where() instead of ->having() no groupBy in here....

Comment: @koalaok yes, same.

Comment: how about putting DB::raw into $q->select() 's parameters with other selected fields?

Comment: @koalaok same result

Comment: Please post the result of `$q->toSql();`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I edited

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making a subquery.

Could you dump the query you're trying to execute ?

```
\DB::enableQueryLog()
...
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

Comment: I get an empty array

Answer (score 0):

The method addSelect() is used when you previously has used the select() method in the query builder, if that is not the case, try to change it to

```
$q->select('( 6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . Auth::user()->latitude . '))' .
        '* cos( radians( users.latitude ) )' .
        '* cos( radians( users.longitude )' .
        '- radians(' . Auth::user()->longitude . ') )' .
        '+ sin( radians(' . Auth::user()->latitude . ') )' .
        '* sin( radians( users.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance')->having('distance', '<', $search->distance);
```

or

```
$q->selectRaw('( 6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . Auth::user()->latitude . '))' .
        '* cos( radians( users.latitude ) )' .
        '* cos( radians( users.longitude )' .
        '- radians(' . Auth::user()->longitude . ') )' .
        '+ sin( radians(' . Auth::user()->latitude . ') )' .
        '* sin( radians( users.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance')->having('distance', '<', $search->distance);
```

Comment: I edited, but in the future the user can add a distance or not, so my 2 selects must be separated.